# Emacs gdb, "-i=mi" option seems to disallow additional arguments

Tags: emacs, gdb

I tried `M-x gdb RET gdb -i=mi --args myexec -d 2 -tl 10 -ba 100`

```
Error: you did not specify -i=mi on GDB's command line!
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax here? I usually run gdb exactly like that but without the `-i=mi` flag. I can ofc just run it without args and specify them at the gdb prompt, but that seems annoying to do since I want to be able to launch the debugger with a key binding...